# Pagination on results doesn't work 'afte the first page' other papes repeats the first

Tags: django, pagination, django-templates, django-views

I have an issue with pagination in Django search.html page. After search result, the results on first page of the table is repeated on the next pages continously.
For reference, this is the bit of the template that displays results:

```
{% for result in page_obj.object_list %}
    <p>
        <a href="{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}">{{ result.object.title }}</a>
    </p>
{% empty %}
    <p>No results found.</p>
{% endfor %}

{% if page_obj.has_previous or page_obj.has_next %}
    <div>
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}<a href="?q={{ query }}&page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">{% endif %}&laquo; Previous{% if page_obj.has_previous %}</a>{% endif %}
        |
        {% if page_obj.has_next %}<a href="?q={{ query }}&page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">{% endif %}Next &raquo;{% if page_obj.has_next %}</a>{% endif %}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Would you add the view snippet as well please?

Comment: It's more likely to be a problem with your view/query than with pagination. Depending on how your query is constructed, that can introduce duplicate results.